# on a modelling with differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

here is I think the easy question about the modelling of the problem with diff equation;

The acceleration in $ms^{-2}$, of a particle moving in a straight line at time t seconds is modelled by $a=-\frac{1}{2}v$.

How can we express $a$ in terms of $v$ and $v¹$ ? and for $v(0)=20$, how can we find $v$ in terms of $t$? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In general, if $x$ is the position of the particle, then $v = x'$ and $a = x'' = v'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the dot, $\dot {}$, instead of the prime, ${}^\prime$, to abbreviate $d/dt$ throughout.

$a = -\dfrac{1}{2}v; \tag 1$

$a = \dot v; \tag 2$

(1) and (2) express $a$ in terms of $v$ and $\dot v$, respectively.  Combining them, we find

$\dot v = -\dfrac{1}{2}v; \tag 3$

if we stipulate that $v$ at time $t_0$ takes a given value $v(t_0)$, this ultra-simple ordinary differential equation is possessed of the unique solution

$v(t) = v(t_0)e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t - t_0)}; \tag 4$

with

$v(0) = 20, \tag 5$

we take

$t_0 = 0; \tag 6$

then (4) becomes

$v(t) = v(0)e^{-\frac{1}{2}t} = 20e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}, \tag 7$

which expresses $v$ in terms of $t$.

***Note:***  It strikes me that the real question here is how we know that (4) follows from (3), other than by just simply though astutely guessing.  One well-known derivation starts with the assumption

$\forall t \in \Bbb R, \; v(t) \ne 0; \tag 8$

then division by $v$ is permissible in equation (3), and so doing we obtain

$\dfrac{\dot v}{v} = -\dfrac{1}{2}, \tag 9$

which may be cast in the form

$\dfrac{d}{dt} \ln v = -\dfrac{1}{2}; \tag{10}$

(10) may be readily integrated under the assumption that $v$ takes the value $v(t_0)$ at $t_0$:

$\ln v(t) - \ln v(t_0) = \displaystyle \int_{v(t_0)}^{v(t)} \dfrac{d}{ds} \ln v \; ds = \int_{t_0}^t -\dfrac{1}{2} \; ds = -\dfrac{1}{2}(t - t_0), \tag{11}$

whence

$\ln \dfrac{v(t)}{v(t_0)} = -\dfrac{1}{2}(t - t_0), \tag{12}$

which may be exponentiated to yield

$\dfrac{v(t)}{v(t_0)} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t - t_0)}, \tag{13}$

or

$v(t) = v(t_0)e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t - t_0)}, \tag{14}$

which agrees with (4).

In the case in which assumption (8) fails, that is,

$\exists \tau \in \Bbb R, \; v(\tau) = 0, \tag{15}$

then

$v(t) \equiv 0, \; \forall t \in \Bbb R \tag{16}$

is a solution to (3) satisfying $v(\tau) = 0$; we may thus invoke uniqueness of solutions to infer that (16) is the only such; in this situation (4) and (14) trivially bind; $v(t_0) = 0 $ no matter what $t_0$ may be.  ***End of Note.***